# Why do people pronounce old as ooooooold sometimes?

Tags: cultural-phrases, pop-culture

I was watching Taskmaster UK, and I noticed that Greg or Alex often say "ooooold ."

For example, in [Taskmaster UK Season 8 Episode 1](https://youtu.be/2BNpnbiFlTk?t=418) at 07:04, Greg says "ooooold poo roll", and he has said the same multiple times before, and the audience and everyone laughs at that.

Initially, I just found it annoying, but now I feel like I'm missing out on some cultural reference. I tried googling "oooold" and "oooold taskmaster" and "usage of oooold in UK", but couldn't find anything that answers my question.

What is the significance of an elongated o in old?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149684/discussion-on-question-by-mahesh-bansod-why-do-people-pronounce-old-as-ooooooold); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's stretching it out to emphasize it. He's being sarcastic by including it in the person's nickname, and emphasizing it to draw attention to the sarcasm.

Comment: +1 Just as we might say "t-e-e-e-e-ny little sewing needle" to emphasize its smallness.

Comment: The wolf in the woods is a baaaaaaad one. This is a goooood cocktail!

Comment: See this Q on Writing SE: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/elongated-vowel-sounds [And this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/jq0l1e/is_there_term_for_whats_going_on_when_an_english/) discusses the same thing in multiple languages.